# Final Part of Binary Bomb Lab Phase 5 (Out of 9)

Tags: linux, debugging, assembly, binary, x86

I am working on the binary bomb lab in x86 assembly, at&t version. I am working on this one phase and I can get to the last part of the code but i do not under stand what is going on in this very last few lines.  I am currently on spring break so I can not go to school and I was wondering if I could get any help here. Thank you.

**Okay so I start of by running my program and entering my 3 inputs.**

```
[bomb46]$ gdb bomb 
            GNU gdb (GDB) Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.6.1-80.el7
            Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
            License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
            This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
            There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
            and "show warranty" for details.
            This GDB was configured as "x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu".
            For bug reporting instructions, please see:
            <http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>...
            (gdb) b phase_5
            Breakpoint 1 at 0x8048da4
            (gdb) r answers.txt
            Welcome to my fiendish little bomb. You have 9 phases with
            which to blow yourself up. Have a nice day!
            Phase 1 defused. How about the next one?
            That's number 2.  Keep going!
            One step closer.
            So you got that one.  Try this one.
            7 0 696
```

**I next run through the beggining of the intructions as its setting things up and scanning the inputs**

```
Breakpoint 1, 0x08048da4 in phase_5 ()
Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install glibc-2.17-106.el7_2.8.i686
(gdb) until *0x08048dd6
0x08048dd6 in phase_5 ()
(gdb) disas
Dump of assembler code for function phase_5:
   0x08048da4 <+0>: sub    $0x3c,%esp
   0x08048da7 <+3>: lea    0x2c(%esp),%eax
   0x08048dab <+7>: mov    %eax,0x10(%esp)
   0x08048daf <+11>:    lea    0x27(%esp),%eax
   0x08048db3 <+15>:    mov    %eax,0xc(%esp)
   0x08048db7 <+19>:    lea    0x28(%esp),%eax
   0x08048dbb <+23>:    mov    %eax,0x8(%esp)
   0x08048dbf <+27>:    movl   $0x804a54c,0x4(%esp)
   0x08048dc7 <+35>:    mov    0x40(%esp),%eax
   0x08048dcb <+39>:    mov    %eax,(%esp)
   0x08048dce <+42>:    call   0x8048900 <__isoc99_sscanf@plt>
   0x08048dd3 <+47>:    cmp    $0x2,%eax
=> 0x08048dd6 <+50>:    jg     0x8048ddd <phase_5+57>
   0x08048dd8 <+52>:    call   0x8049515 <explode_bomb>
   0x08048ddd <+57>:    cmpl   $0x7,0x28(%esp)
   0x08048de2 <+62>:    ja     0x8048ee1 <phase_5+317>
   0x08048de8 <+68>:    mov    0x28(%esp),%eax
   0x08048dec <+72>:    jmp    *0x804a5a0(,%eax,4)
   0x08048df3 <+79>:    mov    $0x67,%eax
   0x08048df8 <+84>:    cmpl   $0x2c5,0x2c(%esp)
   0x08048e00 <+92>:    je     0x8048eeb <phase_5+327>
   0x08048e06 <+98>:    call   0x8049515 <explode_bomb>
   0x08048e0b <+103>:   mov    $0x67,%eax
   0x08048e10 <+108>:   jmp    0x8048eeb <phase_5+327>
   0x08048e15 <+113>:   mov    $0x73,%eax
   0x08048e1a <+118>:   cmpl   $0x78,0x2c(%esp)
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---q
Quit
```

**I then hit the jump and hit the next set of instructions is just checking the 1st input number is 7 or less.**

```
(gdb) ni
0x08048ddd in phase_5 ()
(gdb) disas
Dump of assembler code for function phase_5:
   0x08048da4 <+0>: sub    $0x3c,%esp
   0x08048da7 <+3>: lea    0x2c(%esp),%eax
   0x08048dab <+7>: mov    %eax,0x10(%esp)
   0x08048daf <+11>:    lea    0x27(%esp),%eax
   0x08048db3 <+15>:    mov    %eax,0xc(%esp)
   0x08048db7 <+19>:    lea    0x28(%esp),%eax
   0x08048dbb <+23>:    mov    %eax,0x8(%esp)
   0x08048dbf <+27>:    movl   $0x804a54c,0x4(%esp)
   0x08048dc7 <+35>:    mov    0x40(%esp),%eax
   0x08048dcb <+39>:    mov    %eax,(%esp)
   0x08048dce <+42>:    call   0x8048900 <__isoc99_sscanf@plt>
   0x08048dd3 <+47>:    cmp    $0x2,%eax
   0x08048dd6 <+50>:    jg     0x8048ddd <phase_5+57>
   0x08048dd8 <+52>:    call   0x8049515 <explode_bomb>
=> 0x08048ddd <+57>:    cmpl   $0x7,0x28(%esp)
   0x08048de2 <+62>:    ja     0x8048ee1 <phase_5+317>
   0x08048de8 <+68>:    mov    0x28(%esp),%eax
   0x08048dec <+72>:    jmp    *0x804a5a0(,%eax,4)
   0x08048df3 <+79>:    mov    $0x67,%eax
   0x08048df8 <+84>:    cmpl   $0x2c5,0x2c(%esp)
   0x08048e00 <+92>:    je     0x8048eeb <phase_5+327>
   0x08048e06 <+98>:    call   0x8049515 <explode_bomb>
   0x08048e0b <+103>:   mov    $0x67,%eax
   0x08048e10 <+108>:   jmp    0x8048eeb <phase_5+327>
   0x08048e15 <+113>:   mov    $0x73,%eax
   0x08048e1a <+118>:   cmpl   $0x78,0x2c(%esp)
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---q
Quit
```

**I then continue till hit the next jump, which will move eax and then make a jump to a set of instructions depending on what my 1st input was.**

```
(gdb) ni
0x08048de2 in phase_5 ()
(gdb) ni
0x08048de8 in phase_5 ()
(gdb) disas
Dump of assembler code for function phase_5:
   0x08048da4 <+0>: sub    $0x3c,%esp
   0x08048da7 <+3>: lea    0x2c(%esp),%eax
   0x08048dab <+7>: mov    %eax,0x10(%esp)
   0x08048daf <+11>:    lea    0x27(%esp),%eax
   0x08048db3 <+15>:    mov    %eax,0xc(%esp)
   0x08048db7 <+19>:    lea    0x28(%esp),%eax
   0x08048dbb <+23>:    mov    %eax,0x8(%esp)
   0x08048dbf <+27>:    movl   $0x804a54c,0x4(%esp)
   0x08048dc7 <+35>:    mov    0x40(%esp),%eax
   0x08048dcb <+39>:    mov    %eax,(%esp)
   0x08048dce <+42>:    call   0x8048900 <__isoc99_sscanf@plt>
   0x08048dd3 <+47>:    cmp    $0x2,%eax
   0x08048dd6 <+50>:    jg     0x8048ddd <phase_5+57>
   0x08048dd8 <+52>:    call   0x8049515 <explode_bomb>
   0x08048ddd <+57>:    cmpl   $0x7,0x28(%esp)
   0x08048de2 <+62>:    ja     0x8048ee1 <phase_5+317>
=> 0x08048de8 <+68>:    mov    0x28(%esp),%eax
   0x08048dec <+72>:    jmp    *0x804a5a0(,%eax,4)
   0x08048df3 <+79>:    mov    $0x67,%eax
   0x08048df8 <+84>:    cmpl   $0x2c5,0x2c(%esp)
   0x08048e00 <+92>:    je     0x8048eeb <phase_5+327>
   0x08048e06 <+98>:    call   0x8049515 <explode_bomb>
   0x08048e0b <+103>:   mov    $0x67,%eax
   0x08048e10 <+108>:   jmp    0x8048eeb <phase_5+327>
   0x08048e15 <+113>:   mov    $0x73,%eax
   0x08048e1a <+118>:   cmpl   $0x78,0x2c(%esp)
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---q
Quit
```

**I do the next 2 instructions and hit the jump, which brings me to a set that will compare a number 0x2b8(696) and my 3rd input 696.**

```
(gdb) ni
0x08048dec in phase_5 ()
(gdb) ni
0x08048ec6 in phase_5 ()
(gdb) disas
Dump of assembler code for function phase_5:
   0x08048da4 <+0>: sub    $0x3c,%esp
   0x08048da7 <+3>: lea    0x2c(%esp),%eax
   0x08048dab <+7>: mov    %eax,0x10(%esp)
   0x08048daf <+11>:    lea    0x27(%esp),%eax
   0x08048db3 <+15>:    mov    %eax,0xc(%esp)
   0x08048db7 <+19>:    lea    0x28(%esp),%eax
   0x08048dbb <+23>:    mov    %eax,0x8(%esp)
   0x08048dbf <+27>:    movl   $0x804a54c,0x4(%esp)
   0x08048dc7 <+35>:    mov    0x40(%esp),%eax
   0x08048dcb <+39>:    mov    %eax,(%esp)
   0x08048dce <+42>:    call   0x8048900 <__isoc99_sscanf@plt>
   0x08048dd3 <+47>:    cmp    $0x2,%eax
   0x08048dd6 <+50>:    jg     0x8048ddd <phase_5+57>
   0x08048dd8 <+52>:    call   0x8049515 <explode_bomb>
   0x08048ddd <+57>:    cmpl   $0x7,0x28(%esp)
   0x08048de2 <+62>:    ja     0x8048ee1 <phase_5+317>
   0x08048de8 <+68>:    mov    0x28(%esp),%eax
   0x08048dec <+72>:    jmp    *0x804a5a0(,%eax,4)
   0x08048df3 <+79>:    mov    $0x67,%eax
   0x08048df8 <+84>:    cmpl   $0x2c5,0x2c(%esp)
   0x08048e00 <+92>:    je     0x8048eeb <phase_5+327>
   0x08048e06 <+98>:    call   0x8049515 <explode_bomb>
   0x08048e0b <+103>:   mov    $0x67,%eax
   0x08048e10 <+108>:   jmp    0x8048eeb <phase_5+327>
   0x08048e15 <+113>:   mov    $0x73,%eax
   0x08048e1a <+118>:   cmpl   $0x78,0x2c(%esp)
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
   0x08048e1f <+123>:   je     0x8048eeb <phase_5+327>
   0x08048e25 <+129>:   call   0x8049515 <explode_bomb>
   0x08048e2a <+134>:   mov    $0x73,%eax
   0x08048e2f <+139>:   jmp    0x8048eeb <phase_5+327>
   0x08048e34 <+144>:   mov    $0x64,%eax
   0x08048e39 <+149>:   cmpl   $0x1fd,0x2c(%esp)
   0x08048e41 <+157>:   je     0x8048eeb <phase_5+327>
   0x08048e47 <+163>:   call   0x8049515 <explode_bomb>
   0x08048e4c <+168>:   mov    $0x64,%eax
   0x08048e51 <+173>:   jmp    0x8048eeb <phase_5+327>
   0x08048e56 <+178>:   mov    $0x66,%eax
   0x08048e5b <+183>:   cmpl   $0x363,0x2c(%esp)
   0x08048e63 <+191>:   je     0x8048eeb <phase_5+327>
   0x08048e69 <+197>:   call   0x8049515 <explode_bomb>
   0x08048e6e <+202>:   mov    $0x66,%eax
   0x08048e73 <+207>:   jmp    0x8048eeb <phase_5+327>
   0x08048e75 <+209>:   mov    $0x70,%eax
   0x08048e7a <+214>:   cmpl   $0x161,0x2c(%esp)
   0x08048e82 <+222>:   je     0x8048eeb <phase_5+327>
   0x08048e84 <+224>:   call   0x8049515 <explode_bomb>
   0x08048e89 <+229>:   mov    $0x70,%eax
   0x08048e8e <+234>:   jmp    0x8048eeb <phase_5+327>
   0x08048e90 <+236>:   mov    $0x6f,%eax
   0x08048e95 <+241>:   cmpl   $0x329,0x2c(%esp)
   0x08048e9d <+249>:   je     0x8048eeb <phase_5+327>
   0x08048e9f <+251>:   call   0x8049515 <explode_bomb>
   0x08048ea4 <+256>:   mov    $0x6f,%eax
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
   0x08048ea9 <+261>:   jmp    0x8048eeb <phase_5+327>
   0x08048eab <+263>:   mov    $0x64,%eax
   0x08048eb0 <+268>:   cmpl   $0x273,0x2c(%esp)
   0x08048eb8 <+276>:   je     0x8048eeb <phase_5+327>
   0x08048eba <+278>:   call   0x8049515 <explode_bomb>
   0x08048ebf <+283>:   mov    $0x64,%eax
   0x08048ec4 <+288>:   jmp    0x8048eeb <phase_5+327>
=> 0x08048ec6 <+290>:   mov    $0x62,%eax
   0x08048ecb <+295>:   cmpl   $0x2b8,0x2c(%esp)
   0x08048ed3 <+303>:   je     0x8048eeb <phase_5+327>
   0x08048ed5 <+305>:   call   0x8049515 <explode_bomb>
   0x08048eda <+310>:   mov    $0x62,%eax
   0x08048edf <+315>:   jmp    0x8048eeb <phase_5+327>
   0x08048ee1 <+317>:   call   0x8049515 <explode_bomb>
   0x08048ee6 <+322>:   mov    $0x67,%eax
   0x08048eeb <+327>:   cmp    0x27(%esp),%al
   0x08048eef <+331>:   je     0x8048ef6 <phase_5+338>
   0x08048ef1 <+333>:   call   0x8049515 <explode_bomb>
   0x08048ef6 <+338>:   add    $0x3c,%esp
   0x08048ef9 <+341>:   ret    
End of assembler dump.
```

**I finally run through these instructions and come to my last set of instructions.**

```
(gdb) ni
0x08048ecb in phase_5 ()
(gdb) ni
0x08048ed3 in phase_5 ()
(gdb) ni
0x08048eeb in phase_5 ()
(gdb) disas
Dump of assembler code for function phase_5:
   0x08048da4 <+0>: sub    $0x3c,%esp
   0x08048da7 <+3>: lea    0x2c(%esp),%eax
   0x08048dab <+7>: mov    %eax,0x10(%esp)
   0x08048daf <+11>:    lea    0x27(%esp),%eax
   0x08048db3 <+15>:    mov    %eax,0xc(%esp)
   0x08048db7 <+19>:    lea    0x28(%esp),%eax
   0x08048dbb <+23>:    mov    %eax,0x8(%esp)
   0x08048dbf <+27>:    movl   $0x804a54c,0x4(%esp)
   0x08048dc7 <+35>:    mov    0x40(%esp),%eax
   0x08048dcb <+39>:    mov    %eax,(%esp)
   0x08048dce <+42>:    call   0x8048900 <__isoc99_sscanf@plt>
   0x08048dd3 <+47>:    cmp    $0x2,%eax
   0x08048dd6 <+50>:    jg     0x8048ddd <phase_5+57>
   0x08048dd8 <+52>:    call   0x8049515 <explode_bomb>
   0x08048ddd <+57>:    cmpl   $0x7,0x28(%esp)
   0x08048de2 <+62>:    ja     0x8048ee1 <phase_5+317>
   0x08048de8 <+68>:    mov    0x28(%esp),%eax
   0x08048dec <+72>:    jmp    *0x804a5a0(,%eax,4)
   0x08048df3 <+79>:    mov    $0x67,%eax
   0x08048df8 <+84>:    cmpl   $0x2c5,0x2c(%esp)
   0x08048e00 <+92>:    je     0x8048eeb <phase_5+327>
   0x08048e06 <+98>:    call   0x8049515 <explode_bomb>
   0x08048e0b <+103>:   mov    $0x67,%eax
   0x08048e10 <+108>:   jmp    0x8048eeb <phase_5+327>
   0x08048e15 <+113>:   mov    $0x73,%eax
   0x08048e1a <+118>:   cmpl   $0x78,0x2c(%esp)
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
   0x08048e1f <+123>:   je     0x8048eeb <phase_5+327>
   0x08048e25 <+129>:   call   0x8049515 <explode_bomb>
   0x08048e2a <+134>:   mov    $0x73,%eax
   0x08048e2f <+139>:   jmp    0x8048eeb <phase_5+327>
   0x08048e34 <+144>:   mov    $0x64,%eax
   0x08048e39 <+149>:   cmpl   $0x1fd,0x2c(%esp)
   0x08048e41 <+157>:   je     0x8048eeb <phase_5+327>
   0x08048e47 <+163>:   call   0x8049515 <explode_bomb>
   0x08048e4c <+168>:   mov    $0x64,%eax
   0x08048e51 <+173>:   jmp    0x8048eeb <phase_5+327>
   0x08048e56 <+178>:   mov    $0x66,%eax
   0x08048e5b <+183>:   cmpl   $0x363,0x2c(%esp)
   0x08048e63 <+191>:   je     0x8048eeb <phase_5+327>
   0x08048e69 <+197>:   call   0x8049515 <explode_bomb>
   0x08048e6e <+202>:   mov    $0x66,%eax
   0x08048e73 <+207>:   jmp    0x8048eeb <phase_5+327>
   0x08048e75 <+209>:   mov    $0x70,%eax
   0x08048e7a <+214>:   cmpl   $0x161,0x2c(%esp)
   0x08048e82 <+222>:   je     0x8048eeb <phase_5+327>
   0x08048e84 <+224>:   call   0x8049515 <explode_bomb>
   0x08048e89 <+229>:   mov    $0x70,%eax
   0x08048e8e <+234>:   jmp    0x8048eeb <phase_5+327>
   0x08048e90 <+236>:   mov    $0x6f,%eax
   0x08048e95 <+241>:   cmpl   $0x329,0x2c(%esp)
   0x08048e9d <+249>:   je     0x8048eeb <phase_5+327>
   0x08048e9f <+251>:   call   0x8049515 <explode_bomb>
   0x08048ea4 <+256>:   mov    $0x6f,%eax
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
   0x08048ea9 <+261>:   jmp    0x8048eeb <phase_5+327>
   0x08048eab <+263>:   mov    $0x64,%eax
   0x08048eb0 <+268>:   cmpl   $0x273,0x2c(%esp)
   0x08048eb8 <+276>:   je     0x8048eeb <phase_5+327>
   0x08048eba <+278>:   call   0x8049515 <explode_bomb>
   0x08048ebf <+283>:   mov    $0x64,%eax
   0x08048ec4 <+288>:   jmp    0x8048eeb <phase_5+327>
   0x08048ec6 <+290>:   mov    $0x62,%eax
   0x08048ecb <+295>:   cmpl   $0x2b8,0x2c(%esp)
   0x08048ed3 <+303>:   je     0x8048eeb <phase_5+327>
   0x08048ed5 <+305>:   call   0x8049515 <explode_bomb>
   0x08048eda <+310>:   mov    $0x62,%eax
   0x08048edf <+315>:   jmp    0x8048eeb <phase_5+327>
   0x08048ee1 <+317>:   call   0x8049515 <explode_bomb>
   0x08048ee6 <+322>:   mov    $0x67,%eax
=> 0x08048eeb <+327>:   cmp    0x27(%esp),%al
   0x08048eef <+331>:   je     0x8048ef6 <phase_5+338>
   0x08048ef1 <+333>:   call   0x8049515 <explode_bomb>
   0x08048ef6 <+338>:   add    $0x3c,%esp
   0x08048ef9 <+341>:   ret    
End of assembler dump.
```

**Here it is doing one final comparison, i printed out the values but this is the point where i really do not understand what it going on i believe i got most of it but i cant seem to get this. Ive noticed that the higher the 1st input number is, the lower %al is, and ive changed the 2nd input number but it can only go so high so ive tried to make 2nd input 50 but it will explode before it can get here.**

```
(gdb) x/d $esp+0x27
0xffffce97: 1840
(gdb) x/b $esp+0x27
0xffffce97: 48
(gdb) x/d $esp+0x27
0xffffce97: 48
(gdb) p $al
$1 = 98
```

**I finally run the last commands, but i know it will not work, and it finally reaches explode bomb.**

```
(gdb) ni
0x08048eef in phase_5 ()
(gdb) ni
0x08048ef1 in phase_5 ()
(gdb) disas
Dump of assembler code for function phase_5:
   0x08048da4 <+0>: sub    $0x3c,%esp
   0x08048da7 <+3>: lea    0x2c(%esp),%eax
   0x08048dab <+7>: mov    %eax,0x10(%esp)
   0x08048daf <+11>:    lea    0x27(%esp),%eax
   0x08048db3 <+15>:    mov    %eax,0xc(%esp)
   0x08048db7 <+19>:    lea    0x28(%esp),%eax
   0x08048dbb <+23>:    mov    %eax,0x8(%esp)
   0x08048dbf <+27>:    movl   $0x804a54c,0x4(%esp)
   0x08048dc7 <+35>:    mov    0x40(%esp),%eax
   0x08048dcb <+39>:    mov    %eax,(%esp)
   0x08048dce <+42>:    call   0x8048900 <__isoc99_sscanf@plt>
   0x08048dd3 <+47>:    cmp    $0x2,%eax
   0x08048dd6 <+50>:    jg     0x8048ddd <phase_5+57>
   0x08048dd8 <+52>:    call   0x8049515 <explode_bomb>
   0x08048ddd <+57>:    cmpl   $0x7,0x28(%esp)
   0x08048de2 <+62>:    ja     0x8048ee1 <phase_5+317>
   0x08048de8 <+68>:    mov    0x28(%esp),%eax
   0x08048dec <+72>:    jmp    *0x804a5a0(,%eax,4)
   0x08048df3 <+79>:    mov    $0x67,%eax
   0x08048df8 <+84>:    cmpl   $0x2c5,0x2c(%esp)
   0x08048e00 <+92>:    je     0x8048eeb <phase_5+327>
   0x08048e06 <+98>:    call   0x8049515 <explode_bomb>
   0x08048e0b <+103>:   mov    $0x67,%eax
   0x08048e10 <+108>:   jmp    0x8048eeb <phase_5+327>
   0x08048e15 <+113>:   mov    $0x73,%eax
   0x08048e1a <+118>:   cmpl   $0x78,0x2c(%esp)
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
   0x08048e1f <+123>:   je     0x8048eeb <phase_5+327>
   0x08048e25 <+129>:   call   0x8049515 <explode_bomb>
   0x08048e2a <+134>:   mov    $0x73,%eax
   0x08048e2f <+139>:   jmp    0x8048eeb <phase_5+327>
   0x08048e34 <+144>:   mov    $0x64,%eax
   0x08048e39 <+149>:   cmpl   $0x1fd,0x2c(%esp)
   0x08048e41 <+157>:   je     0x8048eeb <phase_5+327>
   0x08048e47 <+163>:   call   0x8049515 <explode_bomb>
   0x08048e4c <+168>:   mov    $0x64,%eax
   0x08048e51 <+173>:   jmp    0x8048eeb <phase_5+327>
   0x08048e56 <+178>:   mov    $0x66,%eax
   0x08048e5b <+183>:   cmpl   $0x363,0x2c(%esp)
   0x08048e63 <+191>:   je     0x8048eeb <phase_5+327>
   0x08048e69 <+197>:   call   0x8049515 <explode_bomb>
   0x08048e6e <+202>:   mov    $0x66,%eax
   0x08048e73 <+207>:   jmp    0x8048eeb <phase_5+327>
   0x08048e75 <+209>:   mov    $0x70,%eax
   0x08048e7a <+214>:   cmpl   $0x161,0x2c(%esp)
   0x08048e82 <+222>:   je     0x8048eeb <phase_5+327>
   0x08048e84 <+224>:   call   0x8049515 <explode_bomb>
   0x08048e89 <+229>:   mov    $0x70,%eax
   0x08048e8e <+234>:   jmp    0x8048eeb <phase_5+327>
   0x08048e90 <+236>:   mov    $0x6f,%eax
   0x08048e95 <+241>:   cmpl   $0x329,0x2c(%esp)
   0x08048e9d <+249>:   je     0x8048eeb <phase_5+327>
   0x08048e9f <+251>:   call   0x8049515 <explode_bomb>
   0x08048ea4 <+256>:   mov    $0x6f,%eax
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
   0x08048ea9 <+261>:   jmp    0x8048eeb <phase_5+327>
   0x08048eab <+263>:   mov    $0x64,%eax
   0x08048eb0 <+268>:   cmpl   $0x273,0x2c(%esp)
   0x08048eb8 <+276>:   je     0x8048eeb <phase_5+327>
   0x08048eba <+278>:   call   0x8049515 <explode_bomb>
   0x08048ebf <+283>:   mov    $0x64,%eax
   0x08048ec4 <+288>:   jmp    0x8048eeb <phase_5+327>
   0x08048ec6 <+290>:   mov    $0x62,%eax
   0x08048ecb <+295>:   cmpl   $0x2b8,0x2c(%esp)
   0x08048ed3 <+303>:   je     0x8048eeb <phase_5+327>
   0x08048ed5 <+305>:   call   0x8049515 <explode_bomb>
   0x08048eda <+310>:   mov    $0x62,%eax
   0x08048edf <+315>:   jmp    0x8048eeb <phase_5+327>
   0x08048ee1 <+317>:   call   0x8049515 <explode_bomb>
   0x08048ee6 <+322>:   mov    $0x67,%eax
   0x08048eeb <+327>:   cmp    0x27(%esp),%al
   0x08048eef <+331>:   je     0x8048ef6 <phase_5+338>
=> 0x08048ef1 <+333>:   call   0x8049515 <explode_bomb>
   0x08048ef6 <+338>:   add    $0x3c,%esp
   0x08048ef9 <+341>:   ret    
End of assembler dump.
(gdb) q
A debugging session is active.

    Inferior 1 [process 18264] will be killed.

Quit anyway? (y or n) y
```

**I was wondering if i could recieve any kind of help, maybe i am missing something, not realizing it, or not understanding completely, I am not sure what to do at this point.**

Comment: Obviously the first number trivially determines the other two, not sure what your problem is. Why couldn't you enter `98` for the second number, if that's what you determined?

Comment: Because when I enter 0 the number it prints out is 48 and when I enter 1 it is 49 entering 2 gives me 50 so entering 50 would give me 98 but the program will not work with that as the input

Comment: ok i figured out my problem and solved it the second input needed to be a char and not a int, thank you for trying to help